# Single delaySubscription equivalent in Completable

Tags: android, kotlin, rx-java2

In one of my tests (I'm new to testing, any feedback is welcome) I can manually trigger the completion of a `Single` by calling `delayer.onComplete()`. With this I'm able to test if the `loadingObservable: LiveData<Boolean>` is set to true when doing a network request and false when its done. How can I achieve the same with a `Completable`?

```
// This test works fine
@Test
fun repositoryGetAllCategoriesBeforeItEnds_loadingObservableValueIsTrue() {
    // Arrange
    val delayer = PublishSubject.create<Void>()
    `when`(categoryRepositoryImpl.getAllCategories()).thenReturn(Single.just(categoryResponse)
        .delaySubscription(delayer))

    // Act
    val categoryViewModel = CategoryViewModel(categoryRepositoryImpl, networkUtils)

    // Assert
    assertEquals(true, categoryViewModel.loadingObservable.value)

    delayer.onComplete()
}

// This test does not compile in the line mentioned below
@Test
fun repositoryPostCategoryBeforeItEnds_loadingObservableValueIsTrue() {
    // Arrange
    val delayer = PublishSubject.create<Void>()
    `when`(categoryRepositoryImpl.getAllCategories()).thenReturn(Single.just(categoryResponse))
    `when`(categoryRepositoryImpl.postCategory(any()))
        .thenReturn(Completable.complete().delaySubscription(delayer)) // <-- THIS LINE DOES NOT COMPILE

    // Act
    val categoryViewModel = CategoryViewModel(categoryRepositoryImpl, networkUtils)
    categoryViewModel.newCategory("new category")

    // Assert
    assertEquals(true, categoryViewModel.loadingObservable.value)

    delayer.onComplete()
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could convert the Subject to Completable:

```
`when`(categoryRepositoryImpl.postCategory(any()))
    .thenReturn(delayer.ignoreElements())
```

Otherwise, you'd have to emulate the `delaySubscription` via `andThen`:

```
delayer.ignoreElements().andThen(Completable.complete())
```